# Heredoc Not Working in PHP

Tags: php

I am learning to build web applications with PHP. However, I keep having issues using heredocs to stick some HTML into the page from within PHP. Basically, I wanna do something like

```
echo $htmlPage;
```

after PHP does some data processing and stuff. But, as the title suggests, its not working for some reason. And I have reason to believe it has something to do with how I made the heredoc, which can be seen below.

Thanks

```
$htmlPage = <<<HTML
            <style>
                .signup
                {
                    border: 1px solid #999999; 
                    font: normal 14px helvatica; 
                    color: #444444; 
                }
            </style>

            <script src="form_validation.js">

            </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                <th cellspan="2" align="center">Sign Up Form</th>
                <form method="post" action="addUser.php" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
                    <tr> 
                        <td>Forename</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="forename"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Surname</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="surname" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="16" name="username" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type = "password" maxlength="12" name="password" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="3" name="age" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>E-mail</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td colspace="2" align="center">
                        <td><input type = "submit" value="Sign Up"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </form>
            </table>

        </body>
    </html>
HTML;
```

Comment: Oh. I guess I should have elaborated more. The way I have it is I have an HTML page with a form that calls my PHP (the page that the code exerps above are taken from) to perform input validation and input sanitation. The validation PHP page starts by dexlaring a variable containing the heredoc. But, when the form is submitted, it brings me to a blank page. I placed an echo statement right after the heredoc declaration before any of my other PHP code that does the processing, just to see if the heredoc was the issue. And since it didn't display, I have reason to believe the issue is the heredoc

Comment: Yup! That fixed it. Haha! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a trailing space and no new line after the closing delimiter per the manual both are required.

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

-http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Error reporting should have thrown an `unexpected end of file`. Here's a functional example:

```
$htmlPage = <<<HTML
            <style>
                .signup
                {
                    border: 1px solid #999999; 
                    font: normal 14px helvatica; 
                    color: #444444; 
                }
            </style>

            <script src="form_validation.js">

            </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                <th cellspan="2" align="center">Sign Up Form</th>
                <form method="post" action="addUser.php" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
                    <tr> 
                        <td>Forename</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="forename"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Surname</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="surname" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="16" name="username" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type = "password" maxlength="12" name="password" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="3" name="age" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td>E-mail</td>
                        <td><input type = "text" maxlength="32" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr> 
                        <td colspace="2" align="center">
                        <td><input type = "submit" value="Sign Up"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </form>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
HTML;
echo $htmlPage;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/bEI2B